# application.properties is ignored, taken from somewhere else

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am having a strange issue (i am new in spring-boot), this is my `application.properties`

```
server.port=8087
spring.datasource.url:${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER_NAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

When runing it localy, it works just fine. BUT when using a staging server, the changes on the code (controller for example) is taken, but the changes in `application.properties` is not! `server.port` for example on my local machine is 8807, but on the staging server is 8080.

Is there some place that the application is taking configuration from?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you starting your application in the staging server? Can you share the script or the command line?

Comment: by this `nohup java -jar /home/username/app-server-0.0.1.jar`

Comment: OK so you are not overriding any property in the command line. In which folder have you put your application.properties? Is application.properties included in your jar?

Comment: i tried to unrar the jar file, i couldn't find the `application.properties`

Comment: That is the issue. Put application.properties in the resource folder then package it into your jar using maven/gradle

Comment: @IssamEL-ATIF thanks! it worked

Comment: Great! Can you add an answer please? It could be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @Issam EL-ATIF, the problem was on the path of my `application.properties`. the mvn won't package it into the jar if it wasn't inside the `resources` path. 
so i just moved the `application.properties` into the `resources` folder and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [documented list of sources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) properties will be loaded from and in what priority.

`application.properties` is at priority 14 of 17, where 1 is highest priority